# jQuery Validation not trigger while pressing keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Jquery validation not check it is true or not while key pressing. It triggered after focus out from the element. After focus out done validation check start while key pressing. Why is this? here has my code

```
   $('input[name=roleName]').keypress(function () {

        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                roleName: {
                    required: true,
                    isRoleUsed: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                roleName: {
                    required: "You have to enter role name"
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Your validation starts in keypress event function. This what your code tell

Comment: yes But I press keys my function does not start. After focus out it start. Basically I want to start my function while pressing any keys

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin is not the jQuery Validation Engine.  Please be more careful when selecting tags.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `.validate()` method never goes inside of a keypress event handler.  It's only the **initialization** method of the plugin and only goes inside of a DOM ready event handler.

Then the `keyup` event is captured automatically once the plugin is initialized.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            roleName: {
                required: true,
                isRoleUsed: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            roleName: {
                required: "You have to enter role name"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/9hf0pr6a/1/**

Note, by default, validation is "Lazy", meaning that you get one attempt to fill out the form before the `required` validation rules are evaluated.  The `keyup` events are not captured until after the first click of the submit button.

Otherwise, you can change the `keyup` behavior to "Eager" validation by over-riding the `onkeyup` option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').validate({
        onkeyup: function(element) {
            this.element(element);
        },
        rules: {
            roleName: {
                required: true,
                isRoleUsed: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            roleName: {
                required: "You have to enter role name"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/9hf0pr6a/**